# What router is best in price to 'convert' 5GHz signal into 2.4GHz as of March 2019 under $50

Tags: networking, router

I have some hardware that runs horribly on 5GHz, so I need to 'force' a 2.4GHz. But we will be using hotspots that are 5GHz, so we need a router to 'convert' this from 5GHz to 2.4GHz. So we will create a hotspot on the router, and use a hotspot at the same time. Ethernet also needs to be available on the router for LAN access.

I'm looking for 'modern' routers, and ideally good in price. But if that's not allowed on this site (it's saying "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed"), just any routers work. I can do the look up for price. But ideally, someone knows a good off the shelf router.

Ideally I don't have to install something like DD-RWT, but if that's actually really useful then I can install it.

I just need to be able to connect to a provided access point only outputting at 5GHz, and then output a 2.4GHz connection.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can define your budget and then the question is less subjective. So, you could change your title to add under $X.Dollars and define your specs in the body.

Comment: The vast majority of consumer routers transmit 5 Ghz and 2.4 Ghz simultaneously. Would purchasing one of these *dual-band routers* work for you? In addition have you checked that your current router isn't a dual band router and you can just turn off your 5 Ghz band in favor of your 2.4?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Okay I added under $50 and some other details.

Comment: @BennettYeo The wifi setup is provided by the venue I'll be at, and they don't have the 2.4 at all for us to use. I'm mostly worried that the router won't be able to connect to another access point. So I was looking for something to be compatible with that.

Comment: "I'm mostly worried that the router won't be able to connect to another access point. So I was looking for something to be compatible with that". If it's connecting to the LAN via ethernet, the band shouldn't matter. If you need to be able to transmit in 2.4, you can buy a dual band (set to 2.4) to use as a AP and then connect it to the LAN via Ethernet as normal.

Comment: @BennettYeo Ah okay I see, I'll look for a dual band router then. Thanks!